# Learning R: How do I output the element of certain y vector elements with indices that correspond to certain x vectors?

Tags: r, vector

So I have two vectors, Dose and Gender. Dose is a vector with numbers that is 100 length and gender is a vector with "female" and "male" values that is also 100 length. How would I go about outputting something like the below sample output if I define what a high dose value is (i.e. High dose being 40, 50, 60, etc.) and I only want female patients?

### Sample Output

[1] "Female High Dose Patient 1 has dose 63"

[1] "Female High Dose Patient 2 has dose 70"

[1] "Female High Dose Patient 3 has dose 63.07"

[1] "Female High Dose Patient 4 has dose 58"

[1] "Female High Dose Patient 5 has dose 75.25"

Answer (score 2):

So first let me create some dummy data for `Gender` and `Dose` as vectors:

```
Gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)
Dose <- round(runif(100, min = 30, max = 70),2)
```

We'll also define `high_dose` here, which can be whatever threshold you prefer:

```
high_dose <- 50
```

## Create a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(Dose = Dose,
                 Gender = Gender)
```

## Use `dplyr` for easier data manipulations:

```
# if you haven't already done so, you'll want to install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Level = ifelse(Dose >= high_dose, "High", "Low"),
         Patient = row_number(),
         Output = paste(Gender, Level, "Dose Patient", Patient, "has dose", Dose))
```

Let's break this down.  First, `mutate` is going to add new columns to our `df`.  We'll start with `Level`, using an `ifelse` statment for if `Dose` is greater than or equal to whatever we defined `high_dose` to be.

Next, I assigned `Patient` arbitrarily as the row number.  You may want to change this if patient number matters.

Finally, the `Output` is pasting these columns together, with anything being in quotes being the same line by line.  If you are only interested in the output, you can call on it simply by `df$Output`

## `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(Dose = Dose,
                 Gender = Gender)

df[, Level := ifelse(Dose >= high_dose, "High", "Low")]
df[, Patient := 1:100]
df[, Output := paste(Gender, Level, "Dose Patient", Patient, "has dose", Dose)]

df$Output
```

## Alternate route:

Truthfully you can do all of this with just the `paste` function, but I think `dplyr` is a better way to see line by line what is happening with your data.

```
paste(Gender, ifelse(Dose >= high_dose, "High", "Low"), 
      "Dose Patient", 1:100, "has dose", Dose)
```

Comment: Can I use data.table to achieve the same output as using dplyr? I am trying to create this code without using additional packages.